# RAID array disk replacement

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid

We recently had a disk fail in our RAID6 array (within warranty) and got it RMA-ed by Seagate. The disk I sent them was a **Seagate Constellation ES.2 (ST33000650NS)**. The disk they returned was a **Seagate Constellation ES.3 (ST3000NM0033)**.

**Old disk**:
SATA 6 GB/s 7200 RPM 64 MB Cache @ 3 TB

**New disk**:
SATA 6 GB/s 7200 RPM 128 MB Cache @ 3 TB

Is the fact they have different cache sizes going to be an issue if I use this new disk in the array, where all the other disks have 64 MB caches?

I don't think it should be a problem (although there might b some minor if not undetectable performance issues?) but any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Does your RAID use disk cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be a problem, especially since it's the MANUFACTURER'S recommended and sanctioned replacement.

Go ahead and replace the drive...

Comment: @Alex What ewwhite said.  Please note, if this drive failed on hours, consider replacing the other drives too.  In other words, if the array has been in use for 3 years or more, the drive probably failed on end of life, and the others are due to fail as well.